# How can I use score_-_min on effects?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to give effects to a player who is holding a certain sword using scoreboard objective but the command block literally just does absolutely nothing, it doesn't even give an output

Comment: What command are you currently trying?

Answer (score 0):

Scoreboard setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add HoldingSword dummy
```

Clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @a HoldingSword 0
/scoreboard players set @a HoldingSword 1 {SelectedItem:<Sword>}
/effect @a[score_HoldingSword_min=1] <effect> [seconds] [amplifier] [hideParticles]
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't help, but try adding:

```
@a[score_HoldingSword_min=1,*score_HoldingSword_max=1*]
```